# How do I add an extra row into a html form upon button click?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to add a new row into a HTML form by clicking on add new. I got some error. And also looking for delete row if clicked mistakenly on add new.

```
     <table id='myTable'>
             <tr>
             <th>Proposer</th>
             <th>Institution</th>
             <th>E-mail</th>
             <th>You will be present <br>(Y/N)</th></tr>

             <tr>
             <td><input type="text" name="proposer" size="20"><span 
 class="text-danger"><?php echo $proposerError; ?></span> &nbsp;</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="institute" size="30"><span 
 class="text-danger"><?php echo $instituteError; ?></span> &nbsp;</td>
             <td> <input type="text" name="email" size="15"> <span 
 class="text-danger"><?php echo $emailError; ?></span> &nbsp;</td>
             <td><input type="text" name="present" size="4"><span 
 class="text-danger"><?php echo $presentError; ?></span></td>
         </tr>




     <a href=" onclick='$("<tr><td><input type="text" name="proposer2" size="20" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="intitute2" size="30"/></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="email2" size="15"/></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="present2" size="4"/></td>
                                </tr>").appendTo($("myTable")); return false;'>Add new</a>

          </table>
```

Comment: For one, your selector is wrong: `$("myTable")` should be `$("#myTable")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first replace your html markup with this

```
<table id='myTable'>
             <tr>
             <th>Proposer</th>
             <th>Institution</th>
             <th>E-mail</th>
             <th>You will be present <br>(Y/N)</th></tr>

             <tr>
             <td><input type="text" name="proposer" size="20"><span 
 class="text-danger"><?php echo $proposerError; ?></span>  </td>
              <td><input type="text" name="institute" size="30"><span 
 class="text-danger"><?php echo $instituteError; ?></span>  </td>
             <td> <input type="text" name="email" size="15"> <span 
 class="text-danger"><?php echo $emailError; ?></span>  </td>
             <td><input type="text" name="present" size="4"><span 
 class="text-danger"><?php echo $presentError; ?></span></td>
         </tr>


          </table>
<a href="#" class="add-more">Add More</a>
```

Then Use this bellow jQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.add-more').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#myTable').append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="proposer2" size="20" /></td><td><input type="text" name="intitute2" size="30"/></td><td><input type="text" name="email2" size="15"/></td><td><input type="text" name="present2" size="4"/></td></tr>');
    });
});
</script>
```

Then let me know the result.
Thanks

Comment: @Sauvik Sikdar ... Nothing is happening once i click on add new button

Comment: It works well fro my end. Please check console of your browser. an let me know if you find any error in console.